# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2}(x^2 + x^{3/2} + x + x^{1/2})dx$ using Simpson's Rule

Tags: integration, approximation, approximate-integration, simpsons-rule, quadrature

I'm running into some troubles while trying to evaluate 
$$\int_{0}^{2}(x^2 + x^{3/2} + x + x^{1/2})dx$$ using Simpson's Rule

---

Simpson's Rule states 
$$Q(f) = \frac{b-a}{6}(f(a) + 4f(\frac{a+b}{2}) +f(b))$$

In our case: 
$$f(x) = x^2 + x^{3/2} + x + x^{1/2}$$
$$a=0, b=2, f(a=0) = 0 $$
$$ f(b=2) = 4 + 2\sqrt{2} + 2 + \sqrt{2} = 3(2 + \sqrt{2})$$
$$f(\frac{a + b}{2}) = f(1) = 4$$
Thus we get

$$\frac{2-0}{6}(0 + 4 \cdot 4 + 3(2 + \sqrt{2})) = \frac{2(22 + 3\sqrt{2})}{6} = \frac{(22 + 3\sqrt{2})}{3} \approx 8.75$$

However, when evaluating the integral, Wolfram Alpha gives $\approx 8.815$.

Simpson's Rule has degree of accuracy three. Because we are dealing with a polynomial of degree two, shouldn't Simpson's Rule give the exact value of the integral back ? Or are those simply rounding errors ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I used WalframAlpha too and got $8.74755$, see: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simpson%27s+rule+x%5E2+%2B+x%5E%283%2F2%29+%2B+x+%2B+x%5E%281%2F2%29+on+%5B0%2C2%5D+with+interval+size+2

Comment: Since the integrand involves $x^{1/2}$ and $x^{3/2}$, it is not a polynomial, so one should not expect an exact fit with Simpson's Rule.

Comment: Just use Simpson's rule with more subdivisions to get a better approximation.

Comment: @awkward Uh yeah, didn't think about that. Thanks a lot.          Also thank you Bernard Massé and Anton Vrodljak for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integral can easily be computed, using the following fact : $$ \left(\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\lbrace -1\right\rbrace\right),\ \int{x^{\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{1+\alpha}+C $$

Thus, $$ \int_{0}^{2}{\left(x^{2}+x^{\frac{3}{2}}+x+x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\mathrm{d}x}=\left[\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{2x^{\frac{5}{2}}}{5}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]_{0}^{2}=\frac{2}{15}\left(35+22\sqrt{2}\right) $$

Comment: That wasn't really what I was asking for. But thanks anyway